# SharePoint Console Output

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I made a class library, and put it in GAC.
It has one C# code file, and I put a Console.WriteLine() statement in.
When I run the Feature, where would I see the output from this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

- System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine()

or

- System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()
  (Will only output text if assembly
  compiled in debug mode)

to output some text. You would then see it in a program like [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx).

But the best way to debug the program (if you ask this question regarding to debugging) i recommend attachking to SharePoint with Visual Studio debugger. Some [debugging tips here](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2008/06/11/SharePoint-Debugging-and-Logging-Tips-and-Tricks.aspx).